# Every time I run my code off of my phone, I get thrown out of the app and back on my computer it pops up with "Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.1"

Tags: swift, xcode

Here is the entire coded

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var gameOver: UIImageView!

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) { //What Happens After you click the "Play" button

    tapsValid = true
    ballChange = true
    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = false
    self.logo.isHidden = true
    self.Play.isHidden = true
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true

    self.Ball.center.x = 178.0
    self.Ball.center.y = 390.0
    self.pillar.center = CGPoint(x: 175.0,y: 436.0)
    self.pillar2.center = CGPoint(x: 214.0,y: 407.0)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.045, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.movement), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    self.pillar3.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar2.center.x, y: pillar2.center.y)
    self.pillar4.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar3.center.x, y: pillar3.center.y)
    self.pillar5.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar4.center.x, y: pillar4.center.y)
    self.pillar6.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar5.center.x, y: pillar5.center.y)
    self.pillar7.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar6.center.x, y: pillar6.center.y)
    self.pillar8.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar7.center.x, y: pillar7.center.y)
    self.pillar9.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar8.center.x, y: pillar8.center.y)
    self.pillar10.center = pillarPlacement(x: pillar9.center.x, y: pillar9.center.y)


    self.pillar.isHidden = false
    self.pillar2.isHidden = false
    self.pillar3.isHidden = false
    self.pillar4.isHidden = false
    self.pillar5.isHidden = false
    self.pillar6.isHidden = false
    self.pillar7.isHidden = false
    self.pillar8.isHidden = false
    self.pillar9.isHidden = false
    self.pillar10.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop2.isHidden = false
    self.pillarTop3.isHidden = false
}
@IBAction func Retry(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBOutlet var gameView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar10: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillar: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pillarTop: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
var timer = Timer()
var tapsValid:Bool?
var ballRight:Bool?
var ballChange:Bool?
var ballCenter: CGPoint?
var pillarCenter: CGPoint?
var pillar2Center: CGPoint?
var pillar3Center: CGPoint?
var pillar4Center: CGPoint?
var pillar5Center: CGPoint?
var pillar6Center: CGPoint?
var pillar7Center: CGPoint?
var pillar8Center: CGPoint?
var pillar9Center: CGPoint?
var pillar10Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTopCenter: CGPoint?
var pillarTop2Center: CGPoint?
var pillarTop3Center: CGPoint?



@IBOutlet weak var scoreBoard: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var retry: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Ball: UIImageView!
//Start Screen
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.logo.isHidden = false
    self.Play.isHidden = false
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.pillar.isHidden = true
    self.pillar2.isHidden = true
    self.pillar3.isHidden = true
    self.pillar4.isHidden = true
    self.pillar5.isHidden = true
    self.pillar6.isHidden = true
    self.pillar7.isHidden = true
    self.pillar8.isHidden = true
    self.pillar9.isHidden = true
    self.pillar10.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop2.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop3.isHidden = true

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if tapsValid == true
    {
        if ballRight == true
        {
            ballChange = false
        } else
        {
            ballChange = true
        }
    }
}

func movement()
{
    ballCenter = self.Ball.center
    pillarCenter = self.pillar.center
    pillar2Center = self.pillar2.center
    pillar3Center = self.pillar3.center
    pillar4Center = self.pillar4.center
    pillar5Center = self.pillar5.center
    pillar6Center = self.pillar6.center
    pillar7Center = self.pillar7.center
    pillar8Center = self.pillar8.center
    pillar9Center = self.pillar9.center
    pillar10Center = self.pillar10.center

    if ballChange == false
    {
        ballRight = false
    } else
    {
        ballRight = true
    }
    if ballRight == true
    {
        Ball.center.x += 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }else
    {
        Ball.center.x -= 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }

    Ball.center.y += 0.5
    pillar.center.y += 5.0
    pillar2.center.y += 5.0
    pillar3.center.y += 5.0
    pillar4.center.y += 5.0
    pillar5.center.y += 5.0
    pillar6.center.y += 5.0
    pillar7.center.y += 5.0
    pillar8.center.y += 5.0
    pillar9.center.y += 5.0
    pillar10.center.y += 5.0

    pillar.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar.center.x, floaty: pillar.center.y, pillarNumber: 1)
    pillar2.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar2.center.x, floaty: pillar2.center.y, pillarNumber: 2)
    pillar3.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar3.center.x, floaty: pillar3.center.y, pillarNumber: 3)
    pillar4.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar4.center.x, floaty: pillar4.center.y, pillarNumber: 4)
    pillar5.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar5.center.x, floaty: pillar5.center.y, pillarNumber: 5)
    pillar6.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar6.center.x, floaty: pillar6.center.y, pillarNumber: 6)
    pillar7.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar7.center.x, floaty: pillar7.center.y, pillarNumber: 7)
    pillar8.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar8.center.x, floaty: pillar8.center.y, pillarNumber: 8)
    pillar9.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar9.center.x, floaty: pillar9.center.y, pillarNumber: 9)
    pillar10.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar10.center.x, floaty: pillar10.center.y, pillarNumber: 10)


}
func movePillarUp(floatx: CGFloat, floaty: CGFloat, pillarNumber: Int) -> (CGPoint)
{

    var center = CGPoint(x: floatx,y: floaty)
    if checkPillarPosition(y: floaty) == true
    {
        switch pillarNumber
        {
        case 1:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar10.center.x, y: self.pillar10.center.y)
            break
        case 2:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar2)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar.center.x, y: self.pillar.center.y)
            break
        case 3:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar3)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar2.center.x, y: self.pillar2.center.y)
            break
        case 4:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar4)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar3.center.x, y: self.pillar3.center.y)
            break
        case 5:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar5)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar4.center.x, y: self.pillar4.center.y)
            break
        case 6:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar6)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar5.center.x, y: self.pillar5.center.y)
            break
        case 7:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar7)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar6.center.x, y: self.pillar6.center.y)
            break
        case 8:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar8)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar7.center.x, y: self.pillar7.center.y)
            break
        case 9:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar9)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar8.center.x, y: self.pillar8.center.y)
            break
        case 10:
            gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar10)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.pillar9.center.x, y: self.pillar9.center.y)
            break
        default:
            break

        }

    }
    return(center)
}
func checkPillarPosition(y: CGFloat) -> (Bool)
{
    var low = false
    if y>720
    {
        low = true
    }
    return(low)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    if let newBallCenter = ballCenter{
        self.Ball.center = newBallCenter
    }
    if let newPillarCenter = pillarCenter{
        self.pillar.center = newPillarCenter
    }
    if let newPillar2Center = pillar2Center{
        self.pillar2.center = newPillar2Center
    }
    if let newPillar3Center = pillar3Center{
        self.pillar3.center = newPillar3Center
    }
    if let newPillar4Center = pillar4Center{
        self.pillar4.center = newPillar4Center
    }
    if let newPillar5Center = pillar5Center{
        self.pillar5.center = newPillar5Center
    }
    if let newPillar6Center = pillar6Center{
        self.pillar6.center = newPillar6Center
    }
    if let newPillar7Center = pillar7Center{
        self.pillar7.center = newPillar7Center
    }
    if let newPillar8Center = pillar8Center{
        self.pillar8.center = newPillar8Center
    }
    if let newPillar9Center = pillar9Center{
        self.pillar9.center = newPillar9Center
    }
    if let newPillar10Center = pillar10Center{
        self.pillar10.center = newPillar10Center
    }
    if let newPillarTopCenter = pillarTopCenter{
        self.pillarTop.center = newPillarTopCenter
    }
    if let newPillarTop2Center = pillarTop2Center{
        self.pillarTop2.center = newPillarTop2Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop3Center = pillarTop3Center{
        self.pillarTop3.center = newPillarTop3Center
    }
}
// This Function Places the Pillars
func pillarPlacement(x:CGFloat , y:CGFloat ) -> (CGPoint)
{
    var pillarNewX:CGFloat
    var pillarNewY:CGFloat

    var random:Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

    if random == 1
    {
        pillarNewX = x + 39
        pillarNewY = y - 29

        if pillarNewX  >= 319
        {
            pillarNewX = x-40
            pillarNewY = y-30
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pillarNewX = x - 40
        pillarNewY = y - 30

        if pillarNewX  <= 17
        {
            pillarNewX = x+39
            pillarNewY = y-29
        }
    }
    var newPillarCenter = CGPoint(x: pillarNewX,y:  pillarNewY)
    return(newPillarCenter)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

The problem pops up here

```
 func movement()
{
    ballCenter = self.Ball.center
    pillarCenter = self.pillar.center
    pillar2Center = self.pillar2.center
    pillar3Center = self.pillar3.center
    pillar4Center = self.pillar4.center
    pillar5Center = self.pillar5.center
    pillar6Center = self.pillar6.center
    pillar7Center = self.pillar7.center
    pillar8Center = self.pillar8.center
    pillar9Center = self.pillar9.center
    pillar10Center = self.pillar10.center

    if ballChange == false
    {
        ballRight = false
    } else
    {
        ballRight = true
    }
    if ballRight == true
    {
        Ball.center.x += 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }else
    {
        Ball.center.x -= 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }

    Ball.center.y += 0.5
    pillar.center.y += 5.0
    pillar2.center.y += 5.0
    pillar3.center.y += 5.0
    pillar4.center.y += 5.0
    pillar5.center.y += 5.0
    pillar6.center.y += 5.0
    pillar7.center.y += 5.0
    pillar8.center.y += 5.0
    pillar9.center.y += 5.0
    pillar10.center.y += 5.0

    pillar.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar.center.x, floaty: pillar.center.y, pillarNumber: 1)
    pillar2.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar2.center.x, floaty: pillar2.center.y, pillarNumber: 2)
    pillar3.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar3.center.x, floaty: pillar3.center.y, pillarNumber: 3)
    pillar4.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar4.center.x, floaty: pillar4.center.y, pillarNumber: 4)
    pillar5.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar5.center.x, floaty: pillar5.center.y, pillarNumber: 5)
    pillar6.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar6.center.x, floaty: pillar6.center.y, pillarNumber: 6)
    pillar7.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar7.center.x, floaty: pillar7.center.y, pillarNumber: 7)
    pillar8.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar8.center.x, floaty: pillar8.center.y, pillarNumber: 8)
    pillar9.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar9.center.x, floaty: pillar9.center.y, pillarNumber: 9)
    pillar10.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar10.center.x, floaty: pillar10.center.y, pillarNumber: 10)


}
```

Specifically this line

```
pillar9.center = movePillarUp(floatx: pillar9.center.x, floaty: pillar9.center.y, pillarNumber: 9)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry If this question was already asked, but, I could not find it anywhere. I am new to Swift and XCode, so if you could go into some depth of what I am doing wrong, that would be lovely and extremely helpful. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on that line? Remove the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from there being a breakpoint set (which should be checked first, of course!) you have a lot of repeated code which can be a great source of errors. Not having your entire project I can't test it all but I've simplified it quite a bit by using an array to hold your pillar `UIImageView` objects:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!

  @IBOutlet weak var gameOver: UIImageView!

  @IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) { //What Happens After you click the "Play" button

    tapsValid = true
    ballChange = true
    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = false
    self.logo.isHidden = true
    self.Play.isHidden = true
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true

    self.Ball.center.x = 178.0
    self.Ball.center.y = 390.0

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.045, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.movement), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // verify that we have more than 2 pillars before we use subscripts
    guard pillars.count > 2 else { return }
    self.pillars[0].isHidden = false
    self.pillars[0].center = CGPoint(x: 175.0,y: 436.0)
    self.pillars[1].center = CGPoint(x: 214.0,y: 407.0)
    var last = self.pillars[1]
    for pillar in self.pillars.suffix(from: 2) {
      last.isHidden = false
      pillar.center = pillarPlacement(center: last.center)
      last = pillar
    }
  }

  @IBAction func Retry(_ sender: Any) {
  }

  // outlet collection
  @IBOutlet var pillars: [UIImageView]!

  @IBOutlet var gameView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pillarTop3: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pillarTop2: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pillarTop: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
  var timer = Timer()
  var tapsValid:Bool?
  var ballRight:Bool?
  var ballChange:Bool?
  var ballCenter: CGPoint?
  var pillarTopCenter: CGPoint?
  var pillarTop2Center: CGPoint?
  var pillarTop3Center: CGPoint?

  @IBOutlet weak var scoreBoard: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var retry: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var Ball: UIImageView!
  //Start Screen
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.gameOver.isHidden = true
    self.retry.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.logo.isHidden = false
    self.Play.isHidden = false
    self.scoreBoard.isHidden = true
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop2.isHidden = true
    self.pillarTop3.isHidden = true

    // set the whole collection at once
    self.pillars.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }

  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if tapsValid == true
    {
      if ballRight == true
      {
        ballChange = false
      } else
      {
        ballChange = true
      }
    }
  }

  func movement()
  {
    ballCenter = self.Ball.center

    if ballChange == false
    {
      ballRight = false
    } else
    {
      ballRight = true
    }

    if ballRight == true
    {
      Ball.center.x += 6.5
      Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    } else
    {
      Ball.center.x -= 6.5
      Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }

    Ball.center.y += 0.5

    // move all the pillars
    pillars.forEach(movePillarUp)
  }

  func movePillarUp(pillar: UIImageView)
  {
    pillar.center.y += 5.0
    if pillar.center.y > 720
    {
      gameView.sendSubview(toBack: pillar)
      pillar.center = pillarPlacement(center: pillar.center)
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  {
    if let newBallCenter = ballCenter{
      self.Ball.center = newBallCenter
    }
    if let newPillarTopCenter = pillarTopCenter{
      self.pillarTop.center = newPillarTopCenter
    }
    if let newPillarTop2Center = pillarTop2Center{
      self.pillarTop2.center = newPillarTop2Center
    }
    if let newPillarTop3Center = pillarTop3Center{
      self.pillarTop3.center = newPillarTop3Center
    }
  }

  // This Function Places the Pillars
  func pillarPlacement(center: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
  {
    var newCenter = center
    if Int(arc4random() % 2) == 1
    {
      newCenter.x += 39
      newCenter.y -= 29

      if newCenter.x >= 319
      {
        newCenter.x -= 40
        newCenter.y -= 30
      }
    }
    else
    {
      newCenter.x -= 40
      newCenter.y -= 30

      if newCenter.x  <= 17
      {
        newCenter.x += 39
        newCenter.y -= 29
      }
    }
    return newCenter
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

You can connect to the `pillars` outlet collection the same way you do a normal outlet, it will appear under the heading "Outlet Connections". The order in which you add the connections will determine the index of each connection. Now all of your pillars can be under one collection and can be handled at once using loops and other methods. This will reduce code size, decrease the chance of errors, and allow for easier development.

Please test this code and see if it clears up your issue.